# Can't use forEach with Filelist

Tags: javascript, file

I'm trying to loop through a `Filelist`:

```
console.log('field:', field.photo.files)
field.photo.files.forEach(file => {
   // looping code
})
```

As you can see `field.photo.files` has a `Filelist`:

[image]

How to properly loop through `field.photo.files`?

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(field.photo.files, file => console.log(file));`

Comment: It's not an array? Is this node.js?

Comment: @connexo: No, `field.photo.files` is an object prototyped on `FileList`; just like `HTMLCollection`, it does not have `Array.prototype` in its prototype chain.

Comment: Simple `for loop` work :)

Answer (score 453, accepted):

A `FileList` is not an `Array`, but it does conform to its contract (has `length` and numeric indices), so we can "borrow" `Array` methods:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(field.photo.files, function(file) { ... });
```

Since you're obviously using ES6, you could also make it a proper `Array`, using the new `Array.from` method:

```
Array.from(field.photo.files).forEach(file => { ... });
```

Comment: Strange, I get this: `Building.vue?92ca:292 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object(…)` with `Array.from`.

Comment: Well, are you sure your variable is `field.photo.files`? I wasn't checking that...

Comment: @Amadan `field.photo.files` is exactly what the `console.log` shows in my question.

Comment: @Amadan Damn, it was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: you can also use the spread operator `[...field.photo.files].map(file => {});`

Comment: Are there any downsides to "borrowing" the `forEach` method? 

Comment: @mcjlnrtwcz I can't think of anything, except legibility.

Answer (score 63):

You can also iterate with a simple for:

```
var files = field.photo.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i]);
}
```

Comment: Lint does not like this.

Answer (score 54):

In ES6 you can use:

```js
[...field.photo.files].forEach(file => console.log(file));
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: This is not a destructuring assignment. It’s [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It will create a new array just for this operation.

Comment: I realise the original question wasn't about `map()` but 95% of my array iterations are `map`/`filter`/`some` etc. so this would be my preferred solution

Answer (score 6):

The [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/) library has a [_forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach) method that loops through all collection entities, such as arrays and objects, including the FileList:

```
_.forEach(field.photo.files,(file => {
     // looping code
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code is in Typescript

```
urls = new Array<string>();

detectFiles(event) {
   const $image: any = document.querySelector('#file');
   Array.from($image.files).forEach((file: any) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: any) => { this.urls.push(e.target.result); }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
for (const file of fileList) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

```
  for (const file of fileInput.files) {
    output.innerText += `\n${file.name}`;
  }
```

in this case

```
  for (const file of field.photo.files) {
    //some code
  }
```

Answer (score -7):

If you are using Typescript you can do something like this:
For a variable `files` with a type `FileList[]` or `File[]` use:

```
for(let file of files){
    console.log('line50 file', file);
}
```