# Angular 11 + RxJS: concatMap for each array item to call ReplaySubject Observable and finalize not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular11

I am not an expert with Rxjs. I have the following code. I am trying to upload multiple files and for each file, i want to base64 convert and have all the result in final array. Below code is not working and the `finalize` is not invoked at all. Can anyone help me what the problem with my code?

```js
private validateSelectedFiles(files: FileList): void {
  this.spinnerService.show();
  from(files)
    .pipe(
      concatMap(f => this.convertFile(f)),
      finalize(() => {
        console.log('finalize'); //not coming here
        this.spinnerService.hide();
      }),
      scan((acc, curr) => {
        acc.push(curr)
        return acc;
      }, [])
    ).subscribe(result => {
      console.log('result', result); //Only once it is coming here
    })
}

private convertFile(file: File): Observable<string> {
  const result  = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    result.next(btoa(event.target.result.toString()))
  };
  return result;
}
```

Expected functionality:

1. for each upload files, convert it to base64
2. get the array of base64 converted result for further processing

Following code worked for me:

```
private convertAttachmentsToBase64(): void {
        forkJoin(Array.from(this.addedFiles).map(file => this.convertFile(file)))
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            finalize(() => this.spinnerService.hide()),
        )
        .subscribe((result) => this.attachmentsToUpload = result);      
    }   



// Convert file to Base64   
    private convertFile(file: File): Observable<AttachmentToUpload> {
        const result  = new Subject<AttachmentToUpload>();
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            result.next({
                fileName: file.name,
                data: btoa(event.target.result.toString())
            })
            result.complete();
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`finalize()` is a tear-down handler that is called when the chain is terminated (after source Observable completes, errors or the chain is unsubscribed).

In your case you're using `concatMap()` to merge another Observable into the chain. However, you're merging `ReplaySubject` that never completes on its own so the chain is never terminated and thus `finalize()` is never invoked.

It doesn't look like you even need to be using `ReplaySubject` so you can complete the `Subject` immediately when the file is loaded.

```
private convertFile(file: File): Observable<string> {
  const result  = new Subject<string>();
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    result.next(btoa(event.target.result.toString()));
    result.complete();
  };
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest the following

1. Use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) + [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) + [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `from` + `scan` combination.
2. Use [`new Observable()`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) to create an observable instead of a `ReplaySubject`.
3. I don't see a HTTP request in the question at the moment. I've added it using a `switchMap` operator.
4. I am not sure if the `convertFile()` actually converts the file to Base64. As an alternative you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281449/6513921) solution.
5. Important: `forkJoin` will only emit if all the source observable emit. So if the `onload` function isn't triggered by the `FileReader()`, the `forkJoin` won't emit and the `finalize` and `subscribe` won't be triggered.

```js
private validateSelectedFiles(files: FileList): void {
  forkJoin(Array.from(files).map(file => this.convertFile(file))).pipe(
    switchMap((filesB64) => this.http.post('some url')),
    finalize(() => this.spinnerService.hide())
  ).subscribe({
    next: (result: any) => {
      // handle response
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle errors
    }
  });
}

private convertFile(file: File): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable((observer: any) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      observer.next(btoa(event.target.result.toString()));
      observer.complete();
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  });
}
```

Update: Add `Array#from()` for `FileList` (credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40902462/6513921)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. FIrstly not able to use Array#map with FileList
And in my code i am using btoa to convert base64. solution in the example you provided not fitting into my api. thanks anyway.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi: You could use `Array.from(files)`. I've updated the answer. Naturally, converting using `btoa()` could be used as well. It was only a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Michael. this was really useful and the forkJoin worked for my case.