# React Loop Through FileList and Display

Tags: reactjs, filelist

I am trying to loop through a FileList in React and not having any luck.

[image]

I have read this article on [Can't use forEach with Filelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902437/cant-use-foreach-with-filelist) and with it's help I am able to print to the console.  And this [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx?rq=1) article to help with the loop part however I am not able to display any results.

```
renderEligibilityDocs(e) {
var proctorDocChanges = this.state.proctorDocChanges;
var files = proctorDocChanges[313];
console.log("files", files);
if (files) {
  var post = Array.from(files).forEach(file => {
    return (
      <div key={file.name}>
        <h2>file: {file.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  });

  Array.from(files).forEach(file => console.log("Print to Console " + file.name));
  return <div>
    {post}
  </div>;

} else {
  return <div>
    <span>No Files Uploaded</span>
  </div>;
}
```

}

What is the concept that I am missing to display the files in the H tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to capture or render the output you should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `forEach`.

`forEach` executes a function for each element but it doesn't do anything with the return values, whereas `map` builds an array from them.

```js
if (files) {
  return Array.from(files).map(file => {
    return (
      <div key={file.name}>
        <h2>file: {file.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
else {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` method doesn't return anything. This is fine for your second loop where you just want to do a `console.log`, but your first loop needs to return something - you should use `map` there.

You can also move the `map` statement into the return statement:

```
if (files) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from(files).map(f => (
        <h2 key={f.name}>file: {f.name}</h2>
      )}
    </div>
   )
}
```